# Jquery insertbefore before document loaded

Tags: jquery, insertafter

For a project I need to move the position of a DIV. The only way I can do this is with jQuery. I'm not able to edit other files to achieve the result I want.

Now I tried using the `insertAfter()` or `insertBefore()` function. This works but when I load the page on my phone, the div jumps to the right place after I touch the screen.

Is there a way to let it move the div before anything shows up?

Document ready is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

My code:

```
     jQuery(".cta-buttons").insertAfter(".slideshow");
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: No code no help? I guess people here know the function insertAfter()... But here is my code: jQuery(".cta-buttons").insertAfter(".slideshow");

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to hide the `html` until the page is loaded
CSS:

```
html{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   $("html").css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Not the best thing to do though, because it will force inline styling.